# What is meaning of SQL error "Each function argument is an expression, not a query"

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery, having

I have a table `customer_purchases` with 3 columns: `customer_id`, `product_id`, `quantity`, where each `customer_id` can buy multiple products having different quantities.

I need to find customers whose maximum quantity bought (among all the products purchased) is greater than average quantity of every/each customer. I am using Big Query.

I wrote the following query :

```sql
SELECT customer_id 
FROM customer_purchases
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING MAX(quantity) > MAX(SELECT AVG(quantity) 
                           FROM `farmers_market.customer_purchases`
                           GROUP BY customer_id)
ORDER BY customer_id
```

But I get this error:

> Each function argument is an expression, not a query; to use a query as an expression, the query must be wrapped with additional parentheses to make it a scalar subquery expression

What does this mean, and how do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You want something more like this:

```
SELECT p.customer_id 
FROM customer_purchases p
group by p.customer_id
having sum(p.quantity) > (select avg( (select sum(p0.quantity) 
                        from `customer_purchases` p0
                        group by p0.customer_id) ) )
order by customer_id
```

Note the extra set of parentheses inside the `avg()` function. Also noticed that I changed which aggregate functions you were using, since the original functions were not correct for the desired results.

Comment: Hi Joel. It didn't work. I ran the query suggested by you. It threw following error:
```sql
Scalar subquery produced more than one element
```

Comment: What is the problem if subquery produces more than one element. ```avg()``` function can have more than one elements as input.

Comment: @DharminderSingh Not sure, since I don't have your data, but one possibility is confusing the two instances of the table. We might also need another layer of `select` query.  I'm updating to disambiguate them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please change the below query to the below format

```
SELECT customer_id 
FROM customer_purchases
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING MAX(quantity) > MAX((SELECT AVG(quantity) 
                           FROM `farmers_market.customer_purchases`
                           GROUP BY customer_id))
ORDER BY customer_id
```

2. After changing if you are getting the error "sql Scalar subquery produced more than one element"  then please run the below query

```
SELECT customer_id 
FROM customer_purchases
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING MAX(quantity) > MAX((SELECT AVG(quantity) 
                           FROM `farmers_market.customer_purchases`
                           ))
ORDER BY customer_id
```

When you are finding the average and using the `group by`, then it's finding average quantity for each customer id. After this the `max()` is happening again for each customer id, which is returning multiple results to the outer query for comparison. As per definition, Scalar subqueries cannot produce more than a single row. This is the reason I have removed the group by and its going to show the result.

Comment: I think you people need to brush up sql concepts. You have removed group by.
`MAX((SELECT AVG(quantity) 
                           FROM `farmers_market.customer_purchases`
                           ))`
Let me know one thing. What is the use of `MAX()` in this? The subquery will return only one `AVG(quantity)` value. `MAX` of a single value is the value itself. Although this query executes successfully, gives a wrong answer.